# How to create a custom field when using WCF RIA?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I have a table with "first name" and "last name". When binding to a datagrid I need to have a column named "name", which is "first name" + SPACE + "last name".

I am using a DomainDataSource tag in XAML, is there any method to bind a column "first name" + SPACE + "last name"?

Is there any method like defining a class to have for the table in EDMX?

```
Public string fullname { get { return firstName+"_"+lastName; } }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I added a `xxxxx.shared.cs` to added a column to return to client side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% certain I understand the problem, but a couple solutions come to mind:

1. Your query against the database can return a virtual column or
2. You can add a view to the db with the name column created out of the first and last or
3. You can give your business object a name property that would be set from the first and last and would get the full name

-jesse